# How to use state information with className in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have two CSS classes named .Toolbar and .Toolbarnew, upon scrolling after `window.scrolly>200` i want my `div` to be style as per `.Toolbarnew` and before 200 to be styled as per `.Toolbar` (i am using css module)

Here is my code:

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';

import classes from './Toolbar.css';


class Toolbar extends Component{
    state={
        name:'Toolbar'
    }

    listenScrollEvent = e => {
        console.log(window.scrollY);
        if (window.scrollY > 200) {
          this.setState({name: 'Toolbarnew'})
        } else if(window.scrollY < 200) {
          this.setState({name: 'Toolbar'})
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent)
    }


    render(){

        return(
            <div className={classes.this.state.name}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>    

        )
    }
}

export default Toolbar;
```

I hardcoded `className={classes.Toolbar}` and wrote `console.log(this.state.name)` after render() to check if the value is being updated. It turns out that the value was successfully being updated.

But when i use `className={classes.this.state.name}` i get the error message as
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')`

Can anyone help me on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What does `classes` look like?  If it's just CSS, it's not going to have a `this`.

Comment: ``classes`` is provided by the css module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this:

```
<div className={classes[this.state.name]}>
 {this.props.children}
</div>
```

You are getting error: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')**

Because you are trying to access the property **this** in **classes** which does not exist (undefined).

Instead use class name dynamically, `classes[this.state.name]`. This means you are accessing property name (which is set in this.state.name) in **classes** defined in object i.e. `classes["Toolbar"] => classes.Toolbar`